# How the Apportable UIKit is implemented?

Tags: apportable

How does Apportable UIKit is implemented? Is it

- Pure GL implementation?
- Wrapper on Android Java classes?
- Hybrid of both?

and,

- How is performance loss when I display UIKit elements over GL drawing? Is it acceptable? Can I get some numbers?

This is important because I need to predict VRAM usage and performance. To know whether Apportable UIKit implementation suits for intermixing with GL.